# Xamarin Forms Webview causing: error inflating class

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a WebView on a content page in Xamarin forms but when I view the WebView and go back a page and navigate on the app shell it causing the following error:

```
Binary XML file line #1 in com.xxx.xxx:layout/rootlayout: Binary XML file line #1 in com.xxx.xxx:layout/rootlayout: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

I have narrowed this down to this WebView. it PushsAsync to the page on a button press as no other pages do it and if I remove the WebView and replace it with a label it works perfectly. Could this be that something is still happening with the WebView and maybe I need to destroy it on disappearing etc. I am not sure what the actual error is as it is just the above. This only happens on Android.

All my solution is fully updated to the latest versions.

Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually indicates that there is an issue with the layout XML file that defines the root layout of your page. It's possible that the WebView is causing some issue with the layout when navigating back to the page.

One thing you can try is to override the OnDisappearing method of your content page and call the WebView's Dispose method to ensure that it is properly cleaned up when the page is no longer visible.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    if (webView != null)
    {
        webView.Dispose();
        webView = null;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, you can try removing the WebView from the layout and see if the error still occurs. If the error disappears, you can try adding the WebView back to the layout and see if the error reappears. This can help you isolate the issue to the WebView.

Another thing you can try is to wrap the WebView in a StackLayout or another layout container to ensure that it's properly contained within the layout and doesn't interfere with other elements on the page.

```
<StackLayout>
    <WebView Source="https://www.example.com" />
</StackLayout>
```

If it doesn't work, you may need to provide more details about your layout and code so that we can better understand the issue.

Comment: The much higher answer rate and the verboseness suggest this has been generated by [ChatGPT_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: for some reason in Xamarin you cannot be webView.Dispose(); on a webview component

Answer (score 0):

In general, this problem can be caused by the following reasons:

- Layout id conflicts.
- There are properties in the layout file that are not configured correctly.
- There is a problem with the resource file (such as the picture is too large).